# Producing an Oozie workflow using Java

Tags: java, hadoop, oozie

Does someone has an idea if it is possible writing *Oozie workflow* using **Java**.  I'm currently defining them using *XML* and I think we could improve reusability if I was able to use OOP.  I would be happy if I could generate the xml from java classes or even better if I could run the workflow from Java.

The solutions I have in mind right now are:

1. Create Java POJO from Oozie XSD (using JAXB), code workflow in Java
   and then output the result in XML.
2. Use **oozie-core** library and find out, without documentation, how to use *ActionExecutor*.

Also, if the idea doesn't make any sense I would like to know.  Thank you!

Comment: Similar post (no good answers) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352814/generating-oozie-workflows-using-java-code

Comment: Without documentation? https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/DG_Examples.html#Java_API_Example And Oozie already uses OOP for each action node. See https://github.com/apache/oozie/tree/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/action

Comment: The first link you gave me is the client, that works if you point OozieClient.APP_PATH to a folder where you have a workflow.xml.  Now, can I use the ActionExecutor in conjunction with the client?  Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I think I found something maybe with conf.setProperty(OozieClient.APP_PATH, workflow.toString()); (Source: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient). I hope hadoop would be able to share the workflow between the master and core nodes.

Comment: Oozie is a distributed workflow engine. The XML file, properties, and necessary libraries should be located on a shared filesystem such as HDFS, yes.

Comment: i am currently using the option1 and its running all good. Creating the workflow by using the Java POJOs for all the oozier actions ans setting the corresponding values. Once the all actions are created, saving it in HDFS location.Using configurations to set the properties related to "job.properties". As you have pointed in the link. And the finally "oozieClient.run(conf)".

Comment: Excellent.  I'll work on the implementation today, thank you guys!